# Binary variable in GEKKO optimization problem

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I have an optimization problem that has a condition such that if the variable value is greater than 0, a certain constraint applies.

I tried to use m.if3 to generate a binary value that assumes the value of 1 if the variable value is greater than 0, but that did not work because the m.if3 condition applies for greater than or equal to 0, and I need it to be strictly greater than 0. Here is an example of the code I had with if3 but it didn't work.

```
x = m.Var(lb=0)
a = m.if3(x,0,1)
m.Equation(b - c == a*f ) #b,c,f are calculated values
```

I also attempted to use a typical if statement condition, but that did not work with the gekko variable (example below).

```
if x>0:
   m.Equation(b - c == f )
```

Is there another way for me to be able to apply this condition (strictly greater than zero)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if3(x,0,1)` is correct for the desired application but the condition that is turned off or on should have `a*()` on both sides of the equation. Alternatively, move all of the expression to one side so that it is:

```py
m.Equation(a*(b-c-f)==0)
```

so that `0==0` when `a=0`. Here is a complete script that demonstrates the solution.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()

b = 0; c=1
f = m.Var()
x = m.Param(-1)
# binary variable (a=0 if x<0, a=1 otherwise)
a = m.if3(x,0,1)
# turn off condition when a==0
m.Equation(a*(b-c-f)==0)

# initialize with IPOPT (NLP solver)
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.solve(disp=False)

# Find integer solution with APOPT (MINLP solver)
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=True)

print(a.value[0])
```

This gives a solution with `a=0` and the equation deactivated. Change `x = m.Param(-1)` to `x = m.Param(1)` to observe a solution with `a=1`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Keeping in mind that I may have over-simplified code example I gave, is there a way to formulate if3 using the variable value (so in the case of your example, the value of f). Unless I'm missing something, doesn't the use of m.Param essentially render the value of x a constant? Which means a will always be the same value. I need the value of a to change based on the value of the variable (f). Also, my condition only applies if the variable value is strictly greater than 0, so it would have to be a is 0 for x<=0 and 1 for x>0.

Comment: There is no problem to use `x=m.Var()`. Because this is a numerical solution, it cannot enforce 'strictly greater than zero'. Try setting a tolerance that is close enough such as `x>1e-4` as the cutoff condition. The modified condition is `a = m.if3(x-1e-4,0,1)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, even at a low tolerance, the condition skews the results. I have shifted to trying to incorporate a binary variable, but upon doing that, my problem has become infeasible. Is it possible that the infeasibility is due to a 0*0 situation where the variable value is 'supposed to be' 0, thus turning off the condition, rendering the b value also 0? Does that create a problem for the solver?

Comment: The equation that is turned off `m.Equation(a*(b-c-f)==0)` when `a=0` may create an underspecified problem that is hard for the solver. One solution is to add a small penalty to the equation so that it has a unique solution when `a=0` such as `m.Minimize(1e-4*(1-a)*(b-c-f)**2)` to minimize the equation residual.

Answer (score 1):

You can flip the variable's sign and flip the conditions to get your desired behaviour:

In `a = m.if3(x,0,1)` a = 0 if x < 0, and a = 1 if x >= 0.

Instead you can do `a = m.if3(-x,1,0)`. Here a = 1 if -x < 0 (equivalent to x > 0).

Using an if statement as in the second part of your question will not work because x does not have a value. It will only have a value after the optimization. And that will be accessed with something like `x.value`, not directly like this, afaik.